# Navigate to specific url on php form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

Not really familiar with PHP but I need to use it to submit a form.

However, I want it to navigate to a page after form submission.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


try
{
$emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Right now, submitting the form takes me to a new page which just shows the $okMessage text

```
<form id="form" class="topBefore" method="post" role="form" action="contact.php">

                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Comment: Can you paste your html code for the form?

Comment: Added html into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php header('Location: somepage.php');

```
if(mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from))
{
header('Location: somepage.php');
}
```

Note: The php mail() function will return true if the message is accepted for delivery but doesn't guarantee that it will be delivered.

Edit: have a look at my simple email function with try catch statement. Compare with your answer maybe it will help you.

```
// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

//post varables from your form
//$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = 'John'; 
//$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = 'johndoe@blah.com';

//Email header
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$header .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ..." . "\r\n";

$emailText = "You have new message from contact form <br/>   ============================ <br/> Name : $name <br/> Email : $email <br/>";

try
{
    if (mail('demo@domain.com', $subject, $emailText, $header))
    {
        header('Location: somepage.php');
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception($errorMessage);
    }
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo 'Message: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Do I remove 
$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}  or the error and okay message

Comment: I'm not really sure what you trying to do with try catch statement on you code but I will show you a simple example of sending email with try catch statement.